# Does Euler's Formula give sin and cos in degrees or radians? (ie. For use in C++?)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If I am using Euler's formula, eg. for solving:

$$e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

And in my equation I end up with some $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ that derived from this, would the sine and cosine operations need to be set up for receiving results in degrees or radians?

I am guessing degrees.

For example, in C++ the operators $\sin$ and $\cos$ work in radians, so if my math equation that came from the Euler's formula is $\sin(x)$, I presume I would code this as:

`sin(degreesToRadians(x))`

Is that correct?

Comment: nope, not correct

Comment: It should be in radians. Note that if you don't see a degree symbol such as $x^\circ$, then it is in radians.

Comment: Euler's Formula assumes $x$ is in radians, as shown in the bumpersticker relation $e^{i\pi}+1=0$.

Comment: Thanks guys. So I can just use C++ $cos(x)$ or $sin(x)$ without any radian conversion then.